# glBlendColor not working on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es

I'm having trouble compositing two images in a GLKView using glBlendColor and glBlendFunc - it seems to not actually set the color, as whatever color I set has no effect on the resulting output. I'm trying to use the glBlendColor to composite images at various opacities on top of an image already in the framebuffer, which is at an opacity of 1.

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong? I'm writing for iOS 9.3, in Xcode 7.3. Here's my code: this replaces image1 with image2, with no transparency, but it should place image2 on top of image1 at 0.5 opacity.

```
let glContext = EAGLContext(API: .OpenGLES3)
let glView = GLKView(frame: view.frame, context: glContext)
let ciContext = CIContext(EAGLContext: glContext)

view.addSubview(glView)


let uiImage1 = UIImage(named: "1.jpg")!
let image1 = CIImage(image: uiImage1)!

let uiImage2 = UIImage(named: "2.jpg")!
let image2 = CIImage(image: uiImage2)!


glView.bindDrawable()

ciContext.drawImage(image1, inRect: image1.extent, fromRect: image1.extent)

glEnable(GLenum(GL_BLEND))
glBlendFunc(GLenum(GL_CONSTANT_ALPHA), GLenum(GL_ONE_MINUS_CONSTANT_ALPHA))
glBlendColor(0, 0, 0, 0.5)

ciContext.drawImage(image2, inRect: image2.extent, fromRect: image2.extent)

glView.display()
```

Comment: I don't have an answer but, should it help somebody else looking at this: I tried throwing in some `glGets` after the `drawImages` and confirmed that the enables and blends were still as set; I also tried switching the blend function to `GL_ONE`, `GL_ONE` and confirmed additive drawing. So I don't think `CIContext` is modifying anything, and all fragments are definitely reaching the output stage.

Comment: @Tommy, thanks for the comment. Yeah, I've had success using CoreImage to do the opacity, and then `glBlendFunc` just to lay the already transparent second image on the first, but if I try to skip CoreImage and use `glBlendColor` to make the opacity, I get no opacity adjustment. Which makes me think the CoreImage context doesn't play well with `glBlendColor` for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps towards finding an answer at all, iOS supports [EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/EXT/EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch.txt), which "provides a mechanism whereby a fragment shader may read existing framebuffer data as input [which] can be used to implement compositing operations that would have been inconvenient or impossible with fixed-function blending"; Apple [explicitly advertises it](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/BestPracticesforShaders/BestPracticesforShaders.html) as being an opportunity to "Fetch Framebuffer Data for Programmable Blending".

It's unclear to me how the observed behaviour would result — additive blend mode is honoured but multiplicative against a blend colour is not — but this may help to explain why expectations may be thwarted.